# What features does the WiiMotion Plus attachment add to a regular remote?

Tags: nintendo-wii, wiimote

Does it make the remote more "accurate," or does it add some features? Either way, why would I want a remote with it over a regular one? Are there games that can only be played with the attachment, or does it just make playing some games easier/better?

Comment: The answers are absolutely correct, if you want a more technical explanation, how the gyroscope "improves" the performance of the accelerometer I recommend you this google tech-talk: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7JQ7Rpwn2k

Comment: @eL13: wow! thanks for that link, that actually helped me with a totally unrelated school project that I'm working on right now!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Wii MotionPlus was created because it **enables the controller to detect horizontal movement** such as thrusting the controller or swinging it horizontally. The original controller could only pick up vertical movement well. It had [a single accelerometer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii_Remote#Sensing) and unfortunately when gravity wasn't involved, its movement detection was sketchy.

Decent games like [Red Steel](http://au.gamespot.com/wii/action/redsteel/index.html) suffered from it - horizontal sword movements would completely fail just because the wiimote couldn't effectively pick it up. Then you'd get [crap like this](http://awkwardzombie.com/index.php?page=0&comic=040207) happening. Red Steel didn't do so well (with a [metacritic score of 55](http://www.metacritic.com/game/wii/red-steel)) due to the controls being pretty much broken. After the Wii MotionPlus came out, so did Red Steel 2 and it was [far](http://www.metacritic.com/game/wii/red-steel-2) [better](http://www.escapistmagazine.com/videos/view/zero-punctuation/1610-Red-Steel-2).

Comment: More specifically, the MotionPlus lets you tell how the Wiimote is rotated.

Answer (score 8):

The Wii Remote itself contains an accelerometer, that can detect acceleration on the x-, y-, and z-axes. The WiiMotion Plus adds a gyroscope, that allows for the remote to detect rotation (which would not be considered movement to the accelerometer), and linear movement. Essentially, it makes the Wii Remote more accurate and allows games to better mimic what the player is doing.

Wii Sports Resort is an example of a game that requires the WiiMotion Plus accessory. IIRC you can't play the game without it. Games need to be designed to manipulate the extra data from the accessory, so I don't believe there are any games where using the accessory is optional.

Comment: Actually, _Rec Room Games_, which is a collection of several games that can be played in a recreation room, has MotionPlus as an option, not a requirement. Albeit not a well-played game, it _is_ an example.