# Wii MotionPlus vs. Wii Remote Plus : is there a difference in quality or gameplay?

Tags: nintendo-wii, wiimote

I would like to know if there any difference between the new Wii Remote Plus and the couple Wii Remote + Wii MotionPlus

I wonder for instance if the "plus" gyroscopes differs in quality.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a duplicate or not because I'm not sure of all the names, just throwing it out there: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34084/what-features-does-the-wiimotion-plus-attachment-add-to-a-regular-remote

Comment: @DoozerBlake That really isn't a duplicate question. It is asking about the MotionPlus accessory by itself; it isn't about a comparison of MotionPlus and RemotePlus.

Answer (score 3):

The sensor capabilities of Wii Remote + MotionPlus and Wii Remote Plus are the same.

> In November 2010 Nintendo released the Wii Remote Plus, a
>   regular-sized Wii Remote that has the functionality of the MotionPlus
>   accessory.

<sup>source [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii_Remote#Wii_Remote_Plus)</sup>

I am not an expert but I personally tested both controls and I didn't recognize any differences in response and sensitiveness.